# Python mocking a class - method called twice

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying my hand at mocking classes and methods, however having difficulty understanding the duplicate output. I have the following:

```py
from unittest import mock

class SimpleClass(object):
    def explode(self):
        return 'KABOOM!'

def test_simple_class():
    obj = SimpleClass()
    print(obj.explode())

test_simple_class() # displays 'KABOOM!'

@mock.patch("testing.SimpleClass")
def mock_simple_class(mock_class):
    print(f'mock_class:{mock_class}')

mock_simple_class()
```

When executing the code above, I receive the following:

```py
KABOOM!
KABOOM!
mock_class:<MagicMock name='SimpleClass' id='4302975248'>
mock_class:<MagicMock name='SimpleClass' id='4302270416'>
```

Any helpful suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you using to execute your script?

Comment: im using terminal (python3 testing.py)

Comment: I get the same behaviour and I can't explain it.

Comment: Its something to do with `unittest`. I get the impression that at the `@mock.patch(...)` line it imports this file, which runs the file again.

Answer (score 1):

An import of this module is performed when patch is utilized, thus this module gets executed. This won’t be an issue when I break out the tests from the actual execution module.

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s because the code is defining “obj” as KABOOM! and is also defining “explode“ as KABOOM! so when it prints it, it finds two objects defined as KABOOM! so prints them both.